# Missing labels in Matplotlib correlation heatmap

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, heatmap, correlation, imshow

I'm playing around with the [abalone dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Abalone) from UCI's machine learning repository.  I want to display a correlation heatmap using matplotlib and imshow.

The first time I tried it, it worked fine.  All the numeric variables plotted and labeled, seen here:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.imshow(df.corr(), cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
labels = df.columns.tolist()
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels,rotation=90, fontsize=10)
ax1.set_yticklabels(labels,fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[successful heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVV9M.png)

Later, I used get_dummies() on my categorical variable, like so:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ['sex'])
```

[resulting correlation matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDYiW.png)

So, if I reuse the code from before to generate a nice heatmap, it should be fine, right?  Wrong!

[What dumpster fire is this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2v8u.png)

So my question is, where did my labels go, and how do I get them back?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get your labels back, you can force matplotlib to use enough xticks so that all your labels can be shown. This can be done by adding

```
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(labels)))
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(len(labels)))
```

before your statements `ax1.set_xticklabels(labels,rotation=90, fontsize=10)` and `ax1.set_yticklabels(labels,fontsize=10)`.

This results in the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!  This was driving me crazy.  I guess I didn't study the set_ticks documentation hard enough.

Comment: Also, can you tell me why the set_xticks suddenly became necessary, whereas it appeared to be automatic with the initial dataset??